# load data after webservice in uitableview

Tags: ios, web-services, uitableview, core-data

hello there i would like to know how to load my uitableview with the data i've receive and not before

for the moment i execute my webservice in the viewDidLoad
i get the data back and save it in core data
then create a NSMutableArray with the data in core data

but it doesn't load the data when i arrive on the screen, i have to switch screen then comeback on it to see my results

is there a way to stop the loading of my uitableview while my data are not received ?

thank you

Comment: put break-point to check if your array is empty??

Answer (score 0):

You can call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after the data has arrived and you created your data source array.

This will cause the `dataSource` of your table view to perform the following three methods that are needed to set up your table:

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSections`

`- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

`- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You can read more about `UITableView` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:).

Comment: i tried it in the viewDidLoad just after my array loading but didn't seems to work :/

Comment: is the array already filled in `viewDidLoad`? i thought you were using a web service? can you post some code?

Comment: i found out how to do it i have to execute my ws in the viewDidLoad and Reload the tableview in viewDidApear :)

Comment: Well that doesnt seem like a good way to solve the issue. If you are using a web service, you should reload the table after you received the results, not in a method from your view controller life cycle.